# Accessing SQL Server Database using web service in android app

Tags: android, web-services, sql-server-2012

How I can access sql server data using web service ?  What I need to access sql server data in android app ? As I am new to web service I dont know how to create web service and consume it in android app.
If any solution to this please suggest me I need it....plz...and if any source code is there then plz post.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

You can access using simple doing server side coding and JSON encoding to access and use web services. 
Simple tutorial is [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) for php and mysql connectivity.